# Display:column no funciona en Safari

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Intento hacer unas cajas flex pero me doy cuenta que en Safari en el móvil no me funciona, me mueve la primera caja hacia arriba del contenedor.

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
 <article class="contenedor">
   <div class="contiene-socios">
     <figure class="decora-socios">
       <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/imagenes/icono-socios.png" alt="" />
     </figure>
     <div class="bloque-contenido contenido-socios">
       <?php
       while(have_posts()){
         the_post();
         ?>
         <div class="contenido-flex">
           <?php the_content();?>
         </div>
         <?php
       }
        ?>
        <div class="contenido-flex">
          <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="campos-form bloque-form form-socios">
              <input class="input-login" type="text" placeholder="Usuario (*)"  />
            </div>
            <div class="campos-form bloque-form form-socios">
              <input class="input-login" type="password" placeholder="Clave (*)"  />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="boton boton-login" value="Acceder" />
          </form>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </article>
```

Y mi CSS es el siguiente:

```
.contenedor{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.contiene-socios{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  border:1px solid $grisClaro;
  border-radius: 16.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16.5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16.5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 16.5px;
    -o-border-radius: 16.5px;
  position:relative;
  padding:45px 42px;
}
.decora-socios{
  width:155px;
  height:155px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-85px;
  left:50%;
  margin:0 auto 0 -77.5px;  
}
.bloque-contenido{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display:flex;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-moz-flex;
    display:-ms-flex;
    display:-o-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -moz-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-justify-content: flex-start;
    -o-justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -moz-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-align-items: flex-start;
    -o-align-items: flex-start;
}
.contenido-flex{
  flex:0 1 40%;
    -webkit-flex:0 1 40%;
    -moz-flex:0 1 40%;
    -ms-flex:0 1 40%;
    -o-flex:0 1 40%;
}
```

Y cuando hago el `@media` simplemente hago esto:

```
  .bloque-contenido{
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -o-flex-direction: column;
  }
```

Me funciona en Chrome, Firefox y Opera en el ordenador pero en el móvil la caja con el texto y el form se van hacia arriba (quedandose por debajo de la imagen que tengo en el tag )

Aquí el ejemplo de cómo se ve en el teléfono y la segunda en el navegador del ordenador (no sé cómo poner las fotos más pequeñas por aquí)

[image: galeria]

[image: ordenador]

Aquí mi HTML como resultado

```
<article class="contenedor">
   <div class="contiene-socios">
     <figure class="decora-socios">
       <img src="imagenes/icono-socios.png" alt="" />
     </figure>
     <div class="bloque-contenido contenido-socios">
                <div class="contenido-flex">
           <p>Si no dispone de su usuario y contraseña, póngase en contacto con la cooperativa.</p>
<p>Nuestra cooperativa consta de una zona privada en la que puede consultar sus datos de socio si ya dispone de su usuario y clave.</p>
         </div>
          <div class="contenido-flex">
          <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="campos-form bloque-form form-socios">
              <input class="input-login" type="text" placeholder="Usuario (*)"  />
            </div>
            <div class="campos-form bloque-form form-socios">
              <input class="input-login" type="password" placeholder="Clave (*)"  />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="boton boton-login" value="Acceder" />
          </form>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </article>
```

Comment: yo  veo siempre el formulario por debajo de la imagen. ¿Cómo debería verse?

Comment: Exacto, debería verse así pero en teléfonos se me superpone la imagen al texto, como si subiese el texto y se pusiese debajo de la imagen y no entiendo por qué

Comment: No me has entendido, yo veo la imagen siempre encima

Comment: Por encima del texto? Viéndolo en el ordenador en tamaños reducidos se ve bien pero en móviles de ve como la captura que he añadido cuando lo que intento es que se vea el texto debajo de la imagen.

Comment: ah ok. Yo no tenía tu imagen ni el texto, puse otra imagen para probar. ¿podrías poner el html generado en lugar del php?

Comment: Puesto, como ves no es nada del otro mundo...algo creo que tiene que tener mi css en esos bloques que hace que no funciona. Lo raro es redimensionar en el ordenador y que se vea bien y en móvil no tenga forma.